# There is some unique identifier that can be captured by code?

Tags: xcode5

I am making an application and request that by code you can capture a unique identifier such as the cell phone number or UID or some value that is unique to each Apple device, is there any way to do that?, the value must be unique for each device .

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NSUUID for that:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html